# where is _mm_prefetch in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c++, sse, prefetch

I would like to use instruction _mm_prefetch. MSDN [specifies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/84szxsww%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#feedback) that it is in header mmintrin.h, but there is not. I use Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: Note that you will most likely find that `_mm_prefetch` does not help performance at all, and may even degrade it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a bug in their documentation. I couldn't find it in `<mmintrin.h>` either, but it appears to be in `<xmmintrin.h>`.

---

This compiles in VS2010:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>

int main()
{

    _mm_prefetch(0,0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello. Can _mm_prefetch prefetch instructions? Thanks.